# How can I supply command line arguments to a script in Enthought Canopy Editor?

Tags: python, enthought

I am using the new Enthought Canopy code editor on OSX (64-bit). To test a script, I need to provide a command-line argument like:

```
import sys
config_file = sys.argv[1]
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to provide a command line argument to the script. I tried using a macro as:

```
def run():
    code_task = get_active_task()
    code_task.run_current_file('config_filename')
```

...but I get an error that `run_current_file` only takes one argument (presumably `self`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing command line argument is not supported currently, but something that we plan to add.

As a work around, you could run the script normally, first, when it would fail, and then get the previous command from IPython history, and manually add in the args required.

Alternatively, you can set `sys.argv` to the args that you want to pass to your script, before running it. This seems sort of hackish to me.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking when I changed to Canopy from EPD that it would be a full-service IDE. I think the workaround I will need to do for now will be just to hard-code the command line stuff while debugging. I was relieved to see that PDB works well with iPython in the Canopy environment, though.